# Receptacle connection with aluminum wiring?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, aluminum-wiring

I recently purchased a home that has some aluminum wiring. The previous owner decided to "upgrade" the receptacles to make it "safer" for me and my family; these changes were made after the general inspection. He added some kind of crimp (yellow) between the wire and the receptacle and then added anti-oxidant paste.

I had two electricians inspect the work:

- The first claimed that it doesn't follow regulations/standards, it was dangerous, and crimps used are not rated for receptacles (usually for electronics) and that there is even more of a chance it will come undone now. He recommended cutting them off and doing the connection directly to the receptacle with the anti-oxidant paste (as it was before)
- The second claimed that it should be fine as long as the anti-oxidant paste was added

Find attached a picture illustrating the crimps (yellow) that was used in the installation (this is a sample the previous owner gave me, the real wiring in my wall is aluminum.

[image]

Now I am reaching out to the community to see who is right...
Are these "crimps" safe and acceptable solutions for the receptacle wiring or do I need to re-install them?

Any advice would be much appreciated, mostly worried about safety and insurances.
Thanks,

Comment: I could be wrong, but that wire looks red-brown leading me to think that it's copper wire and not Aluminium.  Otherwise, I don't know about regulation but those connectors are just fine, provided that a good crimp is used to crimp to the wire. Keen to see what the electrical specialists think, I have also used them when need arose.

Comment: @Hightower The OP states that this is an example and that the real wiring is indeed AL

Comment: Are the existing devices CO/ALR rated?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel not that I am aware of - he used "COSSE FOURCHETTE" PN 12-10CAXCR/6/JAUNE bought from a local hardware store, he states they are made for aluminium.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel just got back from the hardware store and it says "for COPPER use only"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the first electrician is *wrong* in saying that the use of a crimp-type terminal in house wiring is categorically unsafe.  Crimp-type terminals listed under [UL 486A](http://www.maxdao.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/UL-486A-Wire-Connections-and-Soldering-Lugs-for-Use-With-Copper-Conductors.pdf) for use on solid wire of the given gauge are considered acceptable for use in building wiring, as per UL 486A section 1.1:

> These requirements cover pressure wire connectors and soldering lugs for use 
>   with copper conductors according to the National Electrical Code, NFPA 70.

and NEC 110.14(A):

> Terminals. Connection of conductors to terminal parts shall ensure a 
>   thoroughly good connection without damaging the conductors and shall be made 
>   by means of pressure connectors (including set-screw type), solder lugs, or
>   splices to flexible leads. Connection by means of wire-binding screws or studs 
>   and nuts that have upturned lugs or the equivalent shall be permitted for 10 
>   AWG or smaller conductors.
>
> Terminals for more than one conductor and terminals used to connect aluminum 
>   shall be so identified.

However, I would be quite hesitant to call this specific application fully Code-conformant -- garden-variety listed crimp terminals are listed for use with copper wire *only*, and it would be unlikely that the previous homeowner had access to terminals identified for use with aluminum wiring.

EDIT based on updated info about the devices:

Since the existing devices are copper only, your options go as follows (in order of preference):

1. Find an electrician in your area who is qualified on the Tyco/AMP COPALUM system for pigtailing copper to aluminum -- these have a long, successful field service history, but ***require*** a specially qualified electrician to install, and are rather expensive -- you *might* be able to get the seller to shell out for this, though...
2. Use the AlumiConn connectors with a torque screwdriver for pigtailing.  This is something that most electricians can do, or you can DIY if you know your way around electricity and have a torque screwdriver -- the AlumiConn must be torqued to spec to meet its UL listing.
3. Replace *all* the devices with modern CO/ALR types.  This is a last resort as CO/ALR device performance has been historically variable, unfortunately.

Comment: I would strongly doubt the crimps used are rated for aluminum, but then wouldn't applying the anti-oxidant paste solve the problem of compatibility?

Comment: @Jonathan -- not completely -- field anti-oxidant is highly variable in its application.  ***PROPER*** pigtails or new CO/ALR devices are the solution to this problem.

Comment: what about AlumiConn Aluminum to Copper Lugs?

Comment: @Jonathan -- the AlumiConn devices are somewhat new-ish, but they have shown a good test and field history so far.  They'd fall under "proper pigtailing" in my book, barring evidence to the contrary.